# "follow" meaning in "she followed the bankers' and brokers' claims that they had put their problems behind them with this write-down..."

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> From that moment, Meredith Whitney became E.F Hutton: When she spoke, people listened. Her message was clear: If you want to know what these Wall Street firms are really worth, take a cold, hard look at these crappy assets they're holding with borrowed money, and imagine what they'd fetch in a fire sale. The vast assemblages of highly paid people inside them were worth, in her view, nothing. All through 2008, **she followed the bankers' and brokers' claims that they had put their problems behind them with this write-down or** **that capital raise with her own claim**: *You're wrong. You're still not facing up to how badly you have mismanaged your business. You're still not acknowledging billions of dollars in losses on subprime mortgage bonds. The value of your securities is as illusory as the value of your people.*—*The Big Short: Inside the Doomsday Machine* by Michael Lewis—

The sentence in bold unfortunately seems hard for me to comprehend, so here's what I've wondered.

1. Meaning of "follow" in this sentence.(I couldn't find any possible meaning.)
2. I wonder if "that capital raise" is banker's claim or *her* claim (I assume I don't know  the grammar usage of "that" in it.).
3. I would love to hear what this sentence would mean in general in this context.

Comment: The bankers and brokers repeatedly claimed that they had put their problems (problems ***relating to*** or ***with*** the writing down of assets or the raising of capital) behind them. Whenever Whitney encountered such a claim, she made sure that her "counter-claim" ***followed*** (came immediately after) it. I assume "a capital raise" is bankers' jargon for "an act of raising capital".

Comment: I see, and grammar use of "that" in "that capital raise" is just a determiner? Also, I wonder why it is described "or that" when I assume those two things are such connected thing?

Comment: "to follow (something-A) with (something-B)" is the structure here. It means to do something-B right after something-A happens.